# AttributeError: type object x has no attribute y and some other inconsistencies with Python 3.4

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x, metaclass

I'm learning about Python classes and metaclasses.

Below is an example which was modified from the article ["Metaclasses Demystified"](http://web.archive.org/web/20120503014702/http://cleverdevil.org/computing/78/) at the now-defunct website [cleverdevil.org](http://cleverdevil.org/).

```
# metaclass methods

class Meta(type):
    def show(cls):
        return 'I am a Meta class method'

class Mistake(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

But I encounter an error with this print statement:

```
>>> print(Mistake.show())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Mistake' has no attribute 'show'
```

Below is another example of the same kind.

```
# data hiding
class Fruit:
    __price = 0

    def show(self):
        self.__price += 1
        print (self.__price)

objFruit = Fruit()
objFruit.show()
objFruit.show()
objFruit.show()
print (objFruit._Fruit.__price) # error
```

Also, I receive an error for `print 'hello'`, but `print('hello')` works.

I dont understand the background behind all these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three separate problems:

1. Metaclass syntax is [different](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax) in Python 2.x and 3.x:

   > [**PEP 3115**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115): New Metaclass Syntax. Instead of:
   >
   > ```
   > class C:
   >     __metaclass__ = M
   >     ...
   > ```
   >
   > you must now use:
   >
   > ```
   > class C(metaclass=M):
   >     ...
   > ```
   >
   > The module-global `__metaclass__` variable is no longer supported. (It was a crutch to make it easier to default to new-style classes without deriving every class from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object).)
2. The error your code results in as written:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'Fruit' object has no attribute '_Fruit'
   ```

   ... is not difficult to understand: your `Fruit` object `objFruit` doesn't have an attribute `_Fruit`. Double-underscore name-mangling [doesn't work the way you appear to think](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers). This works:

   ```
   print(objFruit._Fruit__price)  # no period
   ```
3. In Python 3, [`print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

**NOTE**: It so happens that the three separate problems you present in this question are fairly trivial to address, but in general, if you have more than one problem, you should [ask about each in a separate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).